# I see edit instead of read more

Tags: functions

I have little problem with my website. at end of every post,  appears [Edit] in this  way instead of read more. I loaded read more plugins to solve the problem but it disappears for hours and comes back. I checked from different computers and the problem still there. 
Can you please help?

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: that edit appears because you are logged in and have the ability to edit the post.  Nothing to do with read more.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes themes include an [Edit] link as a shortcut for logged-in users to get to the edit screen quickly.  If you log out of wp-admin, this should go away.  The public wouldn't see this on the site.

Depending on your theme, you might be able to switch it off with an option, but if not, you could edit the theme to remove the link, but it doesn't do any harm since it would typically only show up for users that have permissions to edit that post.